# Dynamic skybox inside unity without assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there some way to have dynamic skybox? I want to make day night cycle but I need to change skyboxes - ideally with fading out and in animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Skyboxes are really just materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-skybox.html). You can see its properties in the inspector by going to Window > Lighting > Settings and clicking the Material.

[image]

You can modify these properties with the SetFloat function. For example, if I can use the following script to pulse the exposure:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SkyboxPulse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float pulseRate = 0.2f;

    void Update()
    {
        float exposure = RenderSettings.skybox.GetFloat("_Exposure");

        if (exposure < 0.1 || exposure > 1.9)
            pulseRate = -pulseRate;

        RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Exposure", exposure + pulseRate * Time.deltaTime);
        print(RenderSettings.skybox.GetFloat("_Exposure"));
    }
}
```

This script accesses and modifies the variables set in the shader "Skybox/Procedural". **Warning:** Whenever you terminate the skybox, it will remain the same exposure--it won't reset like other objects do after play mode.

Comment: ok, thank you good to know, is there possibility to "load" new skybox via script?

Comment: Yeah, never mind I used my brain and googled it. Thank you for making this clear to me